# Moved the repository from github, and get 3 SyntaxErrors `Unexpected token`

Tags: reactjs, github

Bought a new laptop, moved the repository from github to it. The API server runs successfully, but when I start the server with react I get 3 errors in the browser console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' bundle.js:1 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' vendors~main.chunk.js:1 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' main.chunk.js:1
```

There are no errors in the editor console.

**UPD after answering**

*If anyone has the same problem with git, I solved it by uploading the repository as a zip file.*

Comment: The code example is not enough to get a context about what's going on when the these errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server is returning HTML when you are expecting JSON. The problem is most likely incorrect URL path somewhere in your code or .env file.

Comment: Oh, yes, seems like it really another url

Comment: But may i ask,why my url was localhost:3000, now it localhost:300/<username>/<gitrepository name>

Comment: theres no way for me to know that sorry.

Comment: Anyway, much thanks for answer